# Django access to attributes with self

Tags: python, django

I have the following Form defined in Django and I do not know why I cannot access to the attribute "username" from within the method "save":

```
class ExtendedUserForm(Form):

    required_css_class = 'required'

    username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$', ...)

    def save(self, commit = False):

        User.objects.create_user(username = self.username, 
                                    email = self.email, 
                                    password = self.password1)
```

... whenever I attempt to access it, I get the following exception:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 'ExtendedUserForm' object has no attribute 'username'
```

I am new with Python and I do not fully understand Python classes, despite of having read the official tutorial. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This example is confusing. `save()` is a method used with `ModelForm`s. There is no `save()` method on the regular `Form` class.

Comment: I did not need a ModelForm, a simpler Form is enough for me, since if I use a ModelForm (I already tried this way) with the User model from django.contrib.auth, I get a lot of fields from that model which I do not want to show in a form for the user to register. Therefore, I decided to use a simpler Form and create the 'save' method by myself.

Comment: @LudwikTrammer, do you know if I can use a ModelForm and link it to a Model, such that I can select only a set of fields to be shown in the resulting Form? This might help me a lot, since the User model from contrib.auth has a lot of fields that I do not need to show in the Form for user registration.

Comment: That's what I would think you are doing, but you are calling a non-existing `save()` method on a super class, which makes it confusing.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the code, I made a mistake while writing my question.

Comment: And for your second question: [sure you can](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use), no one expects you to use all fields from your model in your form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleaned form data is available under `self.cleaned_data` dictionary. Considering `username`, `email` and `password1` are `ExtendedUserForm`'s fields, you can write `save` like this:

```
def save(self, commit = False):
    User.objects.create_user(username = self.cleaned_data['username'], 
                                email = self.cleaned_data['email'], 
                                password = self.cleaned_data['password1'])

    return super(ExtendedUserForm, self).save(self, commit = commit)
```

Comment: Okey, I can undestand that Django saves those attributes in that dictionary too; however, if 'self' is an instance of the Class, and that class has a 'username' attribute, why can't I access to those attributes, in accordance with Python interpreter's output?

Comment: @Ricardo, it's because how `DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass` works. It iterates over attributes, collecting fields and manipulating them. When iterated over, a field is being removed from the class's attributes ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L77)).